# wkhtmltopdf error due to unpatched qt on Python Alpine

Tags: docker, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf from multiple HTML, but when i run the command it launches the error

[image: Error]

I've found many other questions about this topic, that require to redownload it with something like this

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/
```

But none of them have worked, I'm not sure if those bin do not work with Alpine, or if something else I should do. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-libs \
    && apk add -u openssl readline xz gcc jpeg-dev zlib-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev libffi-dev cairo \
    && apk add py3-pip py3-pillow py3-cffi py3-brotli python3-dev pango

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        xvfb \
        ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation

RUN apk add --upgrade wkhtmltopdf

# Some more instructions
```

Does someone knows how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more research, I found that yes, the bin from other Linux distros does not work on Alpine, and that you need a specific for the same, so, I checked, and many of the Docker images that did it are not available but for at least one: `madnight/alpine-wkhtmltopdf-builder:0.12.5-alpine3.10-606718795`. So, to make this work you have to pull this image, run it, and once is up, you cp `/bin/wkhtmltopdf` from it, which then you just move to your instance during build up, and that's all.

2 ways to do this, you can just add `COPY --from=madnight/alpine-wkhtmltopdf-builder:0.12.5-alpine3.10-606718795 /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltopdf` to your Dockerfile, which will pull the image, and will take the file from the local image, or if you don't like to pull the whole image just for the bin everytime you mount it on another device, like I mentioned before, you can just pull it, run `docker cp [instance_id]:/bin/wkhtmltopdf .` and then save the bin somewhere on your project, so in the Dockerfile you can just `COPY [path_to_bin]/wkhtmltopdf /bin/` and this way it will work even if you don't have the other image anymore.

Hope this helps someone.